# Gradle Artifactory plugin error

Tags: eclipse, gradle, artifactory

My gradle version is 2.2.1.

I am trying to use the artifactory plugin in gradle (`apply plugin: 'artifactory'`)

This is my code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://172.14.3.93/artifactory/plugins-release'

        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.0.9')
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'artifactory'
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            maven = true

        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release'
            maven = true

        }
    }
}
```

When i run gradle build, this is what i get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Workspace\GradleConfiguration\build.gradle' line: 100

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'GradleConfiguration'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'artifactory']
   > Could not find method add() for arguments [artifactoryPublish, class org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.extractor.BuildInfoTask] on task set.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Also, when i delete all the code that is related to the artifactory and leave only `apply plugin: 'artifactory'`, i get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\OnRights_Workspace\GradleConfiguration\build.gradle' line: 86

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'GradleConfiguration'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'artifactory']
   > Plugin with id 'artifactory' not found.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your plugin version is too old. Try to use the latest ([3.1.1](https://bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-jars/build-info-extractor-gradle/view)).

Comment: ok ive upgraded, my question is, do i need to remove jcenter() repository after i upgraded it? i am currently using mavenCentral() and the artifactory

Comment: if you use Artifactory with the plugin, you should have `jcenter` in `buildscript{}` and no repositories at all in the script itself. The plugin takes care of resolution and deployment.

Comment: currently the version is "4.4.2"

Comment: At the time of writing this post (exactly a year ago) the latest was 3.1.1. Yup, we're working :)

Answer (score 2):

The `buildscript` block tells Gradle where it should be looking for plugins. You've told it that it should only search at http://172.14.3.93/artifactory/plugins-release.

Are you 100% sure that the "artifactory" plugin is actually hosted there?

If you put jcenter in there, like [the instructions say](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin), does it work better?

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
     jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
     classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.1.0"
   }
}
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
```

Comment: As i said, even if i remove the buildscript and leave only the apply plugin, the error remains

Comment: Yes. That's expected. Please don't remove the `buildscript` block, it is needed by Gradle to find the plugin. Just add exactly what the instructions say, and let us know that works. The whole block from the page I linked, under the heading "Build script snippet for use in all Gradle versions". You could also try the other one called "Build script snippet for use in Gradle 2.1 and above".

Comment: I didnt understand why in the generated build script from the artifactory site, its by default tells gradle to look for the plugin in the artifactory...